# php- Aes encrypt using swift/android and decrypt using openssl_decrypt php

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

This is my code:

```
function decrypt($code)
{

    $key = '3552ef55ecdf04324d0fe7234371...';//$key size = 64 bytes
    $iv = 'd20818af907b59c3b15d258dd3969770';//$iv size = 32 bytes
    $key = hash("sha256", $key, true); // $key size = 32 bytes
    $iv = md5($iv,true);  //$iv size = 16 bytes 
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($code), "AES-256-CBC", $key, 0 ,$iv);
 }
```

This function always return FALSE. Note that the key and iv in encryption swift/android are the same.

Comment: You sure the PHP code returns false?

Comment: yeah. the return value for openssl_decrypt is FALSE @C0dekid

Comment: Maybe the encrypting/hashing your input goes wrong and failes to decrypt. But for `$iv` I used this line: `$iv = substr(hash("sha256", $secret_iv), 0, 16);`

Comment: Same result. @C0dekid

Comment: Your `$iv` is always the same?

Comment: Yes it is a fixed value on swift/android/php.@Mjh

Comment: First problem is that you are passing **binary** representation of the key. It should be a string (remove `true` in your hash('sha256...). Second problem is that `$iv` MUST be different every time you *encrypt*, otherwise your encrypted data isn't secure. Basically, your mistake was passing the key in wrong format. When stuff fails, use `openssl_error_string()` to see what went wrong.

Comment: The openssl_error_string() output is : error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length. I removed the true in sha256.@Mjh

Comment: The `$iv` is usually always publicly available and it's sent in HTTP request. It should never be hardcoded and it should change every time you encrypt data - the party which encrypted the data must deliver encrypted string + initialization vector used. If it's not done like that - you're welcoming decryption attacks and they will be successful.

Comment: Okay i'll fix it later on. But why is the final block length is wrong?@Mjh

Comment: Wrong key or wrong IV. Make sure you have the correct data, along with the encryption method. Since you didn't post the relevant android code, we can only guess. If I use hex secret, binary IV and `AES-256-CBC`, I can encrypt / decrypt without issues.

Comment: Update: the data you're decrypting could be in wrong format as well. Is it base64 encoded? How are you receiving it?

Comment: Do you think that it is a padding problem when decrypting? @Mjh

Comment: strlen(base64_decode($code)) return 80 bytes @Mjh